# VBA Code : Filter Form in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I wrote the following VBA code to help me filter some data using Forms in MS Access but it doesn't work :(
This is what I wrote :

```
Private Sub cboObjectKey_AfterUpdate() 
    Dim myObjectKey As String 
    myObjectKey = "Select * from testQueryFilter where ([ObjectID] = " & Me.CboObjectKey & ")"
    Me.subformquery1.Form.RecordSource = myObjectKey
    Me.subformquery1.Form.Requery  
End Sub
```

I receive no error message, but the problem is that it doesn't work...When I try to filter i get prompted with a msg box "enter parameter Value" this shouldn't happen. When I select something from the Drop Down List I would like to see the filter applied. Any Ideas on how I can fix this?

Br,

Comment: What is the datatype of that `[ObjectID]` field?

Comment: It's the name of the column from a table in MSAcces.It's also the column which gives me the Dropdown list based on which i would like to filter.

Comment: When you open that table in Design View, what does Access show you in the "Data Type" column for your ObjectID field?

Comment: Data Type: "Number"..

Comment: Does your "testQueryFilter" query uses any parameters? also you don't need to requery after assigning a record-source.

Comment: OK.  The parameter name is displayed in the input dialog just below the "Enter Parameter Value" heading.  What is that name?

Comment: Ha! Thanks HansUp , this brought me on the right tracks , It seams that the problem was not the code but the drop down button (where I selected ID & Key in the same Drop Down). I changed the button only to ID and it worked. However If I change the Drop Down only to Key ("Short Text" Type Field) and replace in my VBA Code `[ObjectID]` with `[Key]` it still does not prompt me .The Paramater Displayed in the "Enter Paramater Value" msg box is the same as the value I select from the drop down list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 myObjectKey = "Select * from testQueryFilter where ([ObjectID] = " & Me.CboObjectKey & ")"
```

to be

```
myObjectKey = "Select * from testQueryFilter "
```

do you still get prompted?

If so it is a problem with the table or query named testQueryFilter.

If not it is a problem with the text

```
where ([ObjectID] = " & Me.CboObjectKey & ")"
```

change it to

```
where ([ObjectID] = '" & Me.CboObjectKey & "')"
```

and add this line after the above

```
msgbox myObjectKey : debug.print myObjectKey
```

This will show you the SQL being generated.

However, frankly you probably need to us the MasterLinkField  and ChildLinkField

[see this video to help you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yk-OtW4IHNA&list=PLYMOUCVo86jEgD_6ZgePmPOwGixSPr5FZ&index=15)

Comment: Yes! this was the problem.. I mean the problem with the text, Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would be far easier to apply the Master- and ChildLinkFields of the subform control.

The MasterLinkField would be [cboObjectKey]

The ChildLinkField would be [ObjectID]

Zero code is needed for this to work.

Comment: if cboobjectKey combo-box changes its value a refresh is needed either via code or via navigation ^_^